# Direct multiple domains to specific URLs under one domain: Amazon S3 or Apache

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, dns, redirect, amazon-route53

I have a site with user profiles and following address structure:

- www.mywebsite.com/user1
- www.mywebsite.com/user2

I need to allow users to point/redirect their own domains to their respective page on my site, e.g.:

- www.user1owndomain.com --> www.mywebsite.com/user1
- www.user2owndomain.com --> www.mywebsite.com/user2

One external domain can be pointed to one internal page only. Users will setup their DNS manually by adding CNAME/A record. Users will only have a domain, no server, thus they can not redirect via .htaccess.

**So I would need to give CNAME record/A record to users so that they update DNS and redirect their domain to me.**

**Question is:**

1. If my site runs on Amazon S3, can i accomplish that?
2. If yes, how and is there any limit to how many domains can be linked?
3. This can be solved via S3 itself or do i need to use Route 53?
4. Is Linux/Apache server better platform to accomplish this? If yes, how to set it up?

Thank you in advance for sharing your expert opinion.

Comment: You can't use a CNAME to point to an HTTP request path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with CloudFront + s3.  Configure an s3 bucket where you will host all the sites.  Then create a distribution for every top level domain and set s3 website as your origin.  Use origin+path to point to each users site and configure s3 to return the redirect.

Example:
(cf cname) www.userdomain.com 
Origin: mybucket/user1/ (s3 website)
(S3) configure mybucket/user1/index.html object to redirect

I believe the default limit for CloudFront distributions is 200.